# How can I get data from a website and transfer it to a database?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, api

I am creating a quiz game in c++  that will only work on the terminal. questions with multiple choice answers will be presented to the player.

But before that I need to come up with the questions and answers and save it into a database, (I was thinking to use SQLite). But as it will take me forever to write and input like 100 questions into a database, I need to come up with  something for efficient and quicker :D.

So I found this website which has all the questions and the correct answer. So my question is, is it away I can use a function to kind of copy all the questions and answers and add it into a database? Also I already made a record where I am going to store all the questions and answers

Record is called Questions and has 4 different fields:
Questions(QuestionID*, Question, Answers, CorrectAnswer). Example: 101   "Who won the 2014 World Cup?"  "a) Spain b) Germany, c)Argentina d)Brazil"     "b".

My friends are suggesting that I use an API to get the questions from the internet. Is that a correct way?

Many Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer if you review the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question.

Answer (score 1):

> My friends are suggesting that I use an API to get the questions from the internet. Is that a correct way?

An API is most likely the only way to get anything from the internet, because most operating systems don't allow direct access to the networking hardware.

Whether getting the data from the internet by a C++ program is the correct way is another matter. There are better languages and tools for this. I recommend Python.

> How can I get data from a website

With a HTTP request. The C++ standard library does not have an API for making HTTP requests. The internet protocols are specified in a set of RFC documents hosted by the IETF. The main specification for HTTP is [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616). The protocol is extended by several other specifications, most importantly [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818) which specifies HTTPS.

HTTP requests are generally made over the TCP protocol. The C++ standard library does not have an API for TCP connections. TCP is specified in [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793), although it is likely that your operating system provides you with an implementation of TCP. To find out the API provided by your operating system, the first step is to figure out what operating system you are going to use.